# Search and replace line in Python text stream

Tags: python-2.7, stream

I'm trying to parse a text stream in Python. The contents are being checked line-by-line and, when matched, the given line is passed to a function for processing.

The processing is working and the function returns the expected results. However, I've been unable to update the original stream with the new line--the intent is to replace the matched line with the 'text' value that the function returns.

The code I use for this is as follows:

```
import StringIO
for line in StringIO.StringIO(data):
  if line.startswith('MATCHTHIS'):
    meta, text = parse_data(line)
```

Everything works up until this point--that is, 'meta' and 'text' contain the values I expect. But I'm unable to update the specific line in 'data' to reflect the value of 'text'.

`line.replace(line, text)` works within the `if` block but the change doesn't make it back to 'data'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects in you Python, you can't change their values. If you want to change the value inside the `StringIO` buffer, you can do so as with any other file using `seek` and `write`, but replacing lines with different lengths will be a problem.

I suggest modeling the text stream as a list of lines. Ex:

```
text = "line 1\nMATCHTHIS line 2\nline 3"
lines = text.split('\n')

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("MATCHTHIS"):
        meta, new_line = parse_data(line)
        lines[i] = new_line # Replace old line.

 new_text = '\n'.join(lines) # Recreate text with replaced lines.
```

Also, classic console tools like `sed` and piping are perfect for this job.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. ... `sed` isn't an option as this is part of a Python web app. ... I'm curious about strings being immutable. [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) indicates that it can read/write buffers, though I wasn't able to get this working as I wanted (probably due to my inexperience).